# Imprimir conteúdo webview no windows com encondig utf-8

Tags: javafx

Estou tentando imprimir o conteúdo da webview em javafs 2.2, no windows e caracteres especiais não funcional, (vogais acentuadas, ç...) já mudei o charset da aplicação da forma como se segue:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.setProperty("file.encoding","UTF-8");
    Field charset = null;
    try {
        charset = Charset.class.getDeclaredField("defaultCharset");
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    charset.setAccessible(true);
    try {
        charset.set(null,null);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    TagSellApp.launch( args );
}
```

também quando eu escrevo o arquivo para carregar na webview, neste caso eu recebo um documento Document provido da biblioteca org.jsoup:

```
private void initializeWebView(Document document) {
    File file = new File(".tmp/poster.html");

    try {
        FileWriter rec = new FileWriter(file);
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(file, false), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        writer.println(document.outerHtml());
        writer.close();
        rec.close();

        webEngine.load( file.toURI().toURL().toString() );
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    webEngine.reload();
}
```

antes disto quando carrego o Document eu também:

```
html.charset( StandardCharsets.UTF_8 );
```

e mesmo assim, nada disso funciona no windows, tentei outros encoding como CP1252m Iso 8859-1 e o danado do windows não funciona... to alguns dias pesquisando soluções já fiz inúmeros testes alguém já passou por isso e tem a solução?
Agradeço desde já!

Comment: Já tentou usar a versão JavaFX 8? Se sim, tente mudar "StandardCharsets.UTF_8" para "UTF_8" com as aspas

Comment: tentei também... tava observando neste momento que o problema e com as fontes customizadas... há algumas fontes customizadas no css na webview ta tudo normal o problema acontece na hora de imprimir mesmo